# Render video frame via openGLES2 with Android NDK

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, ffmpeg, render

I made a bin code with NDK to get video frames by ffmpeg decoding, and rendered to opengles, but the screen had nothing changed, it still displayed the launcher.

****But***  when i made a apk tolaunch，it always show black。*

my opengles2.0 ini code is below：

```
static int window_init_display(void)
{
    EGLint attribs [] = {
      EGL_RED_SIZE,        8,
      EGL_GREEN_SIZE,      8,
      EGL_BLUE_SIZE,       8,
      EGL_ALPHA_SIZE,      8,
      EGL_DEPTH_SIZE,     16,
      EGL_STENCIL_SIZE,    0,
      EGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS,  0,
      EGL_SAMPLES,         0,
      EGL_SURFACE_TYPE,    EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
      EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
      EGL_NONE
    };

    EGLint w, h, format;
    EGLint numConfigs;
    EGLConfig config;
    EGLSurface surface;
    EGLContext context;

    EGLDisplay display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);

    eglInitialize(display, 0, 0);

    eglChooseConfig(display, attribs, &config, 1, &numConfigs);

    eglGetConfigAttrib(display, config, EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID, &format);

    ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(g_application->window, 0, 0, format);

    surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, g_application->window, NULL);

    eglQuerySurface(display, surface, EGL_WIDTH, &w);    
    eglQuerySurface(display, surface, EGL_HEIGHT, &h);
    LOGI("EGL_WIDTH=%d, EGL_HEIGHT=%d",w,h);

    eglBindAPI(EGL_OPENGL_ES_API);

    EGLint contextAttrs[] =
    {
       EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2,
       EGL_NONE
    };
    context = eglCreateContext(display, config, NULL, contextAttrs);

    if (eglMakeCurrent(display, surface, surface, context) == EGL_FALSE) 
    {         
            LOGW("Unable to eglMakeCurrent");      
            return -1;   
}

    LOGI("OK init EGL !!!!");
```

}

My render code is below:

```
int m_rgbBufferSize = pPicture->iDisplayWidth*pPicture->iDisplayHeight*4;
m_rgbBuffer = new unsigned char[m_rgbBufferSize];

struct SwsContext *m_sw_context=NULL;
m_sw_context = m_dllSwScale.sws_getCachedContext(m_sw_context,
                                                  pPicture->iWidth, pPicture->iHeight, PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
                                                  pPicture->iWidth, pPicture->iHeight, PIX_FMT_RGBA,
                                                  SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);

uint8_t *psrc[] = { pPicture->data[0], pPicture->data[1], pPicture->data[2], 0 };
int srcStride[] = { pPicture->iLineSize[0], pPicture->iLineSize[1], pPicture->iLineSize[2], 0 };
uint8_t *dst[]  = { m_rgbBuffer, 0, 0, 0 };
int dstStride[] = { pPicture->iDisplayWidth*4, 0, 0, 0 };
m_dllSwScale.sws_scale(m_sw_context, psrc, srcStride, 0, pPicture->iDisplayHeight, dst, dstStride);
//LOGV("swscale OK");
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1);
if(textureid == 0)
    glGenTextures(1, &textureid);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureid);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 
                pPicture->iDisplayWidth, pPicture->iDisplayHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_rgbBuffer);
```

Why does nothing display? Should I use abk not bin file to run?

Comment: If it's still displaying the launcher, then your application isn't in the foreground, and the window manager isn't going to make your window visible.

Comment: so how to get it to foreground ?

Comment: Write your program as an Android application, and launch it.

Comment: i made a apk to launch, but it still does not dispay. it always black when launch.so did i make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Surface is default hided from some other views. Check if you have put some View with the surface.  or set surfaceZOrder on top.